# Import csv file into database using grails and GROM

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy

I want to create database table using grails and table name should be same as the CSV file and name of the column should be same as the field name of the CSV file. I'm using postgresqql

Answer (score 1):

Create a domain class whose name is same as the CSV file and whose properties are the same as the fields of the CSV file.

Comment: actually i want to create dynamic domain class and that class name and the properties should be change at the run time.

Comment: Grails domain classes and a relational databases don't fit well to a persistence model that changes at runtime